# How to redirect url to another

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, jquery, url-rewriting

OK...

I have setup things so that when the following page is requested (browser users and servers)

http://www.visualise.ca/?_escaped_fragment_=corona

the website returns the following the content of this (HTML snapshot)

http://www.visualise.ca/corona

Where 'corona' always change, it varies depending on the page the users or servers are requesting. It could also be

http://www.visualise.ca/?_escaped_fragment_=anne-au-cherry

redirecting to

http://www.visualise.ca/anne-au-cherry

Thanks

**UPDATE:** OK let me be more clear. I use AJAX to load my Wordpress post and they appear like this http://www.visualise.ca/#!/corona when loaded. But it's not crawlable by Google that request to serv them as http://www.visualise.ca/?_escaped_fragment_=corona so I modified Wordpress to do so. Now Google can crawl my page and index its content and accessing the HTML snapshot available at http://www.visualise.ca/corona.

The problem is that when I paste the http://www.visualise.ca/#!/corona link to facebook it seems to read the http://www.visualise.ca/?_escaped_fragment_=corona and is unable to read the content. But when I paste directly the http://www.visualise.ca/?_escaped_fragment_=corona link it works, it reads http://www.visualise.ca/corona (The HTML).

So I thought maybe if I could redirect http://www.visualise.ca/?_escaped_fragment_=corona to http://www.visualise.ca/corona it would solve my problem.

Here is the existing .htaccess file

```
#--- DH-PHP handlers ---
AddHandler fastcgi-script fcg fcgi fpl
AddHandler php-fastcgi .php
Action php-fastcgi /cgi-bin/dispatch.fcgi


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Sounds like you've got everything under control then. Was there a question?

Comment: When I paste http://www.visualise.ca/?_escaped_fragment_=corona to Facebook it's ok I see the content of http://www.visualise.ca/corona appear in the preview but not when I type http://www.visualise.ca/?_escaped_fragment_=corona in the browser address bar and press enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common mistake that a lot of people do is trying to match whole URL including query string. The reality is: **when matching URL, the pattern get applied to path part of it and query string has to be matched separately**.

Use this rule: it will issue 301 Permanent Redirect from this kind of URL `/?_escaped_fragment_=corona` to `/corona` (where `corona` can be anything).

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=([^&]*)
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, it answer my question. But I'm trying to do the same thing with http://visualise.ca/#!/corona and it doesn't seem to work. RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^#!/([^&]*)
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1? [R=301,L]

Comment: @Gab It will not work .. as hash (fragment identifier -- everything after `#` including this symbol itself) is **client side ONLY** and never get sent to a server in first place.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is really "how do I do this kind of redirection?". So the answer is here:

There are three ways that I could think of, each with slight differences.

1. Doing the redirection server side
   This basically means you set redirect headers in your response. In php, you could do this using the [header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#103426) function. It can also do a [delayed redirect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#103619), in which case you need to worry about the contents of the page.
2. Doing it using client side using html's ["http-equiv" meta tags](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_meta_http_equiv.asp). This way the page always gets loaded. Example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh).
3. doing it via javascript. Thats you basic document.location.href thing. You need to figure out a way to pass the argument to javascript, or have your JS read it from the address url itself.

Since I've shown you 3 ways of doing this, I really hope that's what you're looking for :P

---

Update after seeing the comments:

The above methods will cause the URL to change. If you don't want the URL to change, but show the *contents* of that other page on your original page, you caould either do that using iframes (baaaad), or do the decent thing and set up [URL](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) [rewriting](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/).

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \?_escaped_fragment_=(.*?) /$1 [L,R=301]
```

is it what are you looking for?

Comment: I added the existing .htaccess file to my question

Comment: Hello, it doesn't redirect :-/